# Como validar si esta asignado y guardar registro BOOTSTRAP Y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, bootstrap

Buen dia solicitando de su ayuda tengo 2 funciones que separadas me funcionan muy bien pero al querer unirlas no funciona me podrian ayudar les dejo el codigo

Este codigo me ayudar a realizar una comparacion de los 2 datos que se ingresan numero de reloj del empleado y el numero del equipo que se le asigno

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";

$codigo_persona = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, stripslashes(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['codigo_persona'])))));
$codigo_equipo = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, stripslashes(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['codigo_equipo'])))));

if (!ctype_alnum($codigo_persona) OR !ctype_alnum($codigo_equipo)) {
    header("Location: index.php?alert=1");
}
else {

    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM asignacion WHERE no_equipo='$codigo_equipo' AND asig_emp='$codigo_persona'")
                                    or die('error'.mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $rows  = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($rows > 0) {
        $data  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    
        header("Location: index.php?alert=3");
    }
    else {
        header("Location: index.php?alert=1");
    }
}

?>
```

Si la validacion esta bien me arroja este mensaje

[image: bien]

De lo contrario arroja esto

Esa es la primera funcion por separado

Ahora esta es la segunda funcion por separado

Aqui realizo el registro del numero de reloj y el numero de equipo escaneados y me registra la entrada y salida del equipo a continuacion dejo el codigo

```
<?php 
require_once "../modelos/Asistencia.php";

$asistencia=new Asistencia();

$codigo_persona=isset($_POST["codigo_persona"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["codigo_persona"]):"";
$codigo_equipo=isset($_POST["codigo_equipo"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["codigo_equipo"]):"";
$iddepartamento=isset($_POST["iddepartamento"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["iddepartamento"]):"";



switch ($_GET["op"]) {
    case 'registrar_asistencia':
        $result=$asistencia->verificarcodigo_persona($codigo_persona);

        if($result > 0) {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chihuahua');
            $fecha = date("Y-m-d");
            $hora = date("H:i:s");

            $result2=$asistencia->seleccionarcodigo_persona($codigo_persona);
            $count2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
               
            $par = abs($count2%2); 

          if ($par == 0){ 
                              
                $tipo = "Entrada";
                $rspta=$asistencia->registrar_entrada($codigo_persona,$codigo_equipo,$tipo);
                //$movimiento = 0;
                echo $rspta ? '<h3><strong>Nombres: </strong> '. $result['nombre'].' '.$result['apellidop'].'</h3><div class="alert alert-success"> Ingreso registrado '.$hora.'</div>' : 'No se pudo registrar el ingreso';
                
          }else{ 
                $tipo = "Salida";
                $rspta=$asistencia->registrar_salida($codigo_persona,$codigo_equipo,$tipo);
                //$movimiento = 1;
                echo $rspta ? '<h3><strong>Nombres: </strong> '. $result['nombre'].' '.$result['apellidop'].'</h3><div class="alert alert-danger"> Salida registrada '.$hora.'</div>' : 'No se pudo registrar la salida';             
        } 
        } else {
                 echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                       <i class="icon fa fa-warning"></i> No hay empleado registrado con esa código...!
                         </div>';
        }

    break;

}
?>
```

[image: GOOD]

Espero me puedan ayudar a darme una idea de como hacer que funcionen ambos juntos o algun ejemplo ya junto de lo que ocupo estoy trabajando con PHP BOOTSTRAP